# How to do rtmp streaming in kurento media server?

Tags: video-streaming, rtmp, fiware, kurento

I was just wondering if there is any feature like RTMP in Kurento Media Server . I need it to stream my vod content . Any ideas ? anyhow RTP can be used for it ?

Thanks
Pawan

Comment: use ffmpeg or gstreamer  to get the H 264 content . Flow could be   WebRTC endpoint -> Kurento Call handler ( Record in chunks ) -> ffmpeg / gstreamer to put it on RTP -> streaming server like wowza - > viewers

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a rtmp endpoint in Kurento, at least yet. But we have streamed content to a Wowza mediaserver using an RTP Endpoint with the last kurento development version. Maybe this can also work for you.

Comment: Hello santoscadenas , I have a made an RTP endpoin t and connected to WebRTC endpoint using media pipeline , could you please specify or direct me to the documentation that specifies the process of streaming content from kurento RTP endpoint to Wowza . ( I have Kurento and wowza installed )

Comment: @Altanai the process is simple:

Comment: igracia - i Would be grateful if you  direct me to any links which have description on linking RTP Endpoint to Wowza

Comment: @Altanai Sorry, it seems that the answer was cut-off. You need to create the RTP endpoint in KMS, and then it will server the video to Wowza. Have a look at [this post](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?38-How-to-set-up-live-streaming-using-a-native-RTP-encoder-with-SDP-file) to serve this in Wowza as RTMP

Comment: @igracia, is there an example of RTP Sender in Kurento? For e.g., there is a receiver (wowza/janus or any other RTP receiver), which wants to connect to RTP sender and expect the stream.

Comment: FYI, my goal is to bridge WebRTC to RTP (through pipeline connect) and then send stream to the external receiver (like Wowza or Janus).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

https://groups.google.com/g/kurento/c/_1jO6ugsAO4/m/Yen1ug25AwAJ

```
//here,  I tested with MediaProfileSpecType.MP4, because i do not build the new javaclient sdk.
MediaProfileSpecType profile = MediaProfileSpecType.FLV;
String filePath = "file:///tmp/test.flv";
RecorderEndpoint recorder = new RecorderEndpoint.Builder(pipeline, filePath)
.withMediaProfile(profile).build();

//build webrtcendpoint 
WebRtcEndpoint webrtcEndpoint = ...;

webrtcEndpoint.connect(recorder);
```

The third post from richmonkey have an example code that I'd test in my computer to stream to youtube.

You gotta use RecorderEndpoint with a media profile.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).