# Kurento Media WebRTC to RTP

Tags: webrtc, rtp, webm, kurento

I am using kurento's master git to make a WebRTC to RTP bridge.

```
MediaPipeline pipeline = kurento.createMediaPipeline();
WebRtcEndpoint webRtcEndpoint = new WebRtcEndpoint.Builder(pipeline).build();
HttpGetEndpoint httpEndpoint=new HttpGetEndpoint.Builder(pipeline).build();

org.kurento.client.Fraction fr= new org.kurento.client.Fraction(1, 30);         
VideoCaps vc= new VideoCaps(VideoCodec.H264,fr);
httpEndpoint.setVideoFormat(vc);

AudioCaps ac= new AudioCaps(AudioCodec.PCMU, 65536);
httpEndpoint.setAudioFormat(ac);

webRtcEndpoint.connect(httpEndpoint);
```

However inspite of this the output video playing is encoded to webm . I have tried various other approaches as well ( using RTP ENdpoint , using Gstream filter , using VLC HTTP to RTP streamer ) . however no method gives me a video playable on safari and IE   ie H264 encoded . Requesting media developers and kurento team for help .

Comment: Hello! Have you solved your problem with streaming WebRTC for non webrtc browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari and IE do not support RTP/H.264. From you code, I understand that you are trying to create a WebRTC to  tag bridge. In that case, the HttpGetEndpoint will provide media through HTTP pseudostreaming. However, Kurento only provides that type of live HTTP pseudostreaming in WebM format. To be best of my knowledge, neither Safari nor IE support WebM, hence what you want to do will not work independenlty on the caps you force to the HttpGetEndpoint. You will be only able to see it working on Chrome, Fireforx or other browsers with WebM support.

The only solution for you could be the HttpGetEndpoint providing media in MP4 format (or any other format supported by IE and Safari), but creating the live stream in that format is very tricky and we (the Kurento team) did not had the time for implementing that and this feature is not in our short term roadmap.

However, we have many users integrating WebRTC with IE and Safari using RTMP. In that case, you need to integrate Kurento with an RTMP capable media server (this can be done in different ways) and later let the RTMP media server to serve media to the browsers.

Comment: Hello lulop  , thanks for replying and establishing that RTMP Server is definitely required which id not in kurento for now . I have used Wowza media server ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203318/how-to-do-rtmp-streaming-in-kurento-media-server)  . However RTP SDP and HTTP stream url dont seem to give me a working output for live stream . Request you to lead me to a documentation / example which directs how to integrate Kurento Endpoints to Wowza and obtain a stream suitable for non webrtc browsers .