# Does kurento support safari and ie?

Tags: internet-explorer, safari, kurento

I have googled some questions like this
[link1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/kurento/r8Z6Dn9b5TY/t-gcvQz4FYEJ) or this [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279144/kurento-media-webrtc-to-rtp) and it seems from this answers that kurento and webrtc doesn't support safari and ie.
But I've heard from one person in skype ( this contact is already lost so can't ask any details now), I've heard that last versions support it using flash.
So I am confused.Do last versions support kurento and webrtc?
I am a little bit more confused as I found this [caniuse.com link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rtcpeerconnection)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Kurento does not support IE, Safari browsers or any browser which does not have webRTC support.

Although, for IE and Safari there exists a workaround.
Using the Temasys webRTC plugin as given [here](https://temasys.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TWPP/Downloading+and+Installing) and updating kurento-utils.js with the changes to work with IE/ Safari, you can have IE and Safari support for your web application that uses Kurento media server 6.2.

You may refer [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kurento/h1HuhGxN75k) on kurento's google group for more help.

I could have mentioned all the steps here again but that will be redundant since they are mentioned in above link.

Please feel free to write in case you need exact steps.

Comment: i just don't understand what plugin means.Is it like some library that i will use while writing code, or user will have to install something?

Comment: It is a browser plugin that user will need to install on on the browser side. Once you have followed the steps to integrate it in your web application as given [https://temasys.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TWPP/How+to+integrate+the+Temasys+WebRTC+Plugin+into+your+website] here.
The user will get a prompt to install the plugin when he visits your web app from IE or safari browser for the first time. After he completes the install your webRTC application will run normally

Comment: You are welcome :) Please upvote if you are able to get it to work

Comment: i am not able to get it work cause we switched to wowza but i will mark ur question as an answer, cause it actually answers my question)

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC is not supported in Safari nor in Internet Explorer. Hence, you cannot use any kind of WebRTC tecnologies on them, including Kurento WebRTC features. However Kurento is not only providing WebRTC, it also provides RTP endpoint capabilities, and through them, it's quite straight-forward to integrate with Wowza media server. Hence, a combination of Kurento and Wowza is suitable for integrating Safari and Internet Explorer (through Flash) with WebRTC applications and systems.

An additional option is to use WebRTC plugins in Safari and Internet Explorer. For example, Temasys provide such plugins and they are compatible with Kurento. Hence, using such plugins makes possible to create WebRTC applications basing on Kurento suitable for interoperating among all major browsers.

Comment: So why should I consider possibillity of using kurento and wowza together? what are the advanteges of this?

Comment: Only because kurento works like torrent-  peer to peer?

Comment: Kurento provides you WebRTC and Wowza RTMP and HLS. Hence, the combination enables you to interoperate WebRTC with IE and Safari.

Comment: and use less server resources?